# Unable to close folder properties dialog

Tags: windows-7

I was trying to help a friend with a file sharing problem, and opened up the security tab, clicked on Edit and Advanced to see if there were any relevant settings. Now, I am unable to close the Properties dialog.

[image]

Things I have tried which do not work:

- Alt-F4
- Clicking X in upper-right corner
- Close button
- Opening properties dialog for the folder again (via right-click) just jumps to that instance
- Closing all Explorer windows
- Deleting the folder `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

However, after deleting the folder and pressing Close/X/Alt-F4, I am presented with this dialog:

[image]

If I press `Continue` then that new dialog goes away and I am still unable to close the Properties dialog. If I press `Cancel` then I get this warning:

[image]

Unfortunately pressing `Edit` or `Advanced` on the `Security` tab does nothing.

Also I can't reboot for a few days because I have several long-running processes which can not be interrupted. I would kill processes but I'm not sure which process belongs to this dialog. I suspect it's the `dllhost.exe (COM Surrogate)` process but I have ~200 processes running and I would hate to kill something important.

How can I kill this dialog? Yes, I could just ignore it, but I can't even minimize it so it keeps popping up and driving me nuts.

Comment: Try running this command from a command prompt: `taskkill /im explorer.exe /f`

Comment: That works, but the UI is gone afterwards. Pressing ctrl-alt-del > Task Manager > New Task > Explorer got it back. Submit this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

1. Open a [command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7), type or paste the following command, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   taskkill /im explorer.exe /f
   ```
2. Bring back the Windows Explorer shell by running this command:

   ```
   start explorer.exe
   ```

   As an alternative, follow these steps:

   - a. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to open the Task Manager.
   - b. Open the **File > New Task (Run...)** menu.
   - c. Type or paste `explorer.exe`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Still works today ! 14/03/2022

Answer (score 0):

You had started changing permissions of the folder, and the windows in your second screenshot were not visible to you (sometimes those windows don't grab the top-most position on the screen, or maybe you flipped to another program, or the windows were on the second screen and you weren't looking over there).

A way to perform a master all-windows-minimize is by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. That will hide your annoying window.

If you've already deleted the folder, then there's no reason to be concerned at all about any inconsistent permissions on deleted files.

Comment: I could also just drag the dialog out of view. But as a programmer, I'm slightly paranoid about leaving random un-closeable dialogs open (memory leaks, corrupt handles, file locks, etc.).